# Difference between $\bigcap F$ and $F \cap$...

Tags: proof-explanation, definition

I don't understand what something like $\bigcap F$ means. Here's an example of where it's used.

**Theorem.** *Suppose $F$ and $G$ are families of sets, and $F \cap G \neq \varnothing$. Then $\bigcap F \subseteq \bigcup G$.*

What's the difference between say $\bigcap F$ and something like $F \cap G$ and what would it mean for some $x \in \bigcap F$?

Comment: $\cap F$ means the intersection of all sets in the family $F$.

Comment: Usually, this is written as $\bigcap F$ (with a big cap!). It means the intersection of all the sets that are members of $F$, i.e. $\{x:\text{$x\in S$ for every $S\in F$}\}$. Likewise, $\bigcup G$ means the union of all of the sets that are members of $G$, i.e. $\{x:\text{$x\in S$ for some $S\in G$}\}$.

Comment: Have you tried proving the theorem?

Comment: @Wakem I just tried proving it. I will post my solution and request critique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say $F = \{ \{0, 1, 2\}, \{ 1, 2, 3\}, \{ 2, 3, 4\} \}$. Then $\bigcap F$ is the intersection of all sets in $F$. That is, $x \in \bigcap F$ if and only if $x \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ and $x \in \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ and $x \in \{ 2, 3, 4\}$. Equivalently, $\bigcap F = \{ 2 \}$. Similarly, $\bigcup F$ is the union of all sets in $F$. That is, $x \in \bigcup F$ if and only if $x \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ or $x \in \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ or $x \in \{ 2, 3, 4 \}$. Equivalently, $\bigcup F = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$.

Now if, say, $G = \{ \{0, 2, 4 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ -1, 3, 5 \} \}$, then $F \cap G = \{ \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \}$. In other words, the families of sets $F$ and $G$ share only one set in common, namely $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$. In this case, $\bigcap F = \{ 2 \}$ and $\bigcup G = \{ -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$.

(Note that the notation $\cap F$ does not really mean anything. Rather, it is $\bigcap F$.)